# How can this code that does factorial to the user input be more optimized?

Tags: python, optimization, factorial

```
a=1
for _ in range(int(input("Enter: "))):
    a=a*(_+1); print(a)
```

This code does the factorial and prints the values as the process goes.
An input of 5 would print:
1
2
6
24
120
It takes the past output value and multiplies the next number in input.

I want to get the same output or even better by only printing after the calculation is done.
But the most important thing I want to achieve is a better optimized code that uses less lines.
One more thing don't use libraries.

Comment: So you mean you want to remove `print(a)`?

Comment: Note that there is `math.factorial` to compute the factorial. The `math` package is a standard one (available by default in Python though it must be imported).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could print only the final result, in a single line using max and a walrus assignment:

```
print( max(1,a:=1,*(a := a*i for i in range(2,int(input("Enter: "))+1))) )
```

*This even works for 0! = 1*

If you want to print all the values in one line, you can write it without the max():

```
print( a:=1, *(a := a*i for i in range(2,int(input("Enter: "))+1)) )
```

Comment: Accomplishes doing factorial in one line of code challenge I was working on.

Answer (score 0):

I guess another way of doing this would be a comprehension but this makes the code hard to read:

```
a=1
print(*(a:=a*(_+1) for _ in range(int(input("Enter: ")))), sep="\n")
```

I would suggest though a more readable way of doing this:

```
n = int(input("Enter: "))
a = 1
products = [a]

for i in range(n):
    a *= i
    products.append(a)

print(*products, sep="\n")
```

Comment: Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

The standard implementation of the factorial function is given by this function.

```py
def factorial(n: int) -> int:
    product: int = 1
    for number in range(1, n + 1):
        product = product * number
    return product
```

Another less efficient but easier to understand way is to use recursion

```py
def factorial_recursive(n: int) -> int:
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return n * factorial_recursive(n - 1)
```

Another alternative method is to use the reduce function.

```py
from functools import reduce 

def factorial_reduce(n: int) -> int:
     numbers: tuple = tuple(range(1, n + 1))
     initial_value: int = 1
     return reduce(lambda current, product: current * product, numbers, initial_value)
```

Comment: Appreciate the help!